# Unordered List doesnt inline

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I have this unordered list with images and its only displaying vertically when i want it sideways.

This is how it looks now.

I have tried dozens of code of `display:inline` or `float:left` but nothing seems to work.

[image]

I want the list to be sideways instead:

this is the HTML:

```css
.gallery-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

#galtitle {
  font-size: 500%;
}

.imggallery {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

ul#list li  {
  display: inline;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="gallery" class="no-padding content-section">
  <div class="gallery-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <h1 id="galtitle">Gallery</h1>
        <div class="imggallery">
          <ul id="list">
            <li>
              <img src="img/michael61.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <p>Visit flyer gallery</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="img/michael61.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <p>Visit flyer gallery</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change some css's. Like:

1. Remove `.imggallery` width.
2. Set `#list` to `display:block`
3. Remove `.img-responsive` from the images.

Just read the css and if something is not clear, ask..

```css
.gallery-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

#galtitle {
  font-size: 500%;
}

.imggallery {
  height: 200px;
  /*width: 200px;*/
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
}

ul#list li  {
  display: inline;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="gallery" class="no-padding content-section">
  <div class="gallery-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <h1 id="galtitle">Gallery</h1>
        <div class="imggallery">
          <ul id="list">
            <li>
              <img src="img/michael61.jpg">
              <span>Visit flyer gallery</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="img/michael61.jpg">
              <span>Visit flyer gallery</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to set `inline` on the `ul`.

Your `li`s contain block elements, so setting them inline doesn't really make sense. Instead, set them to `inline-block`.

Lastly, the `width` on `.imggallery` is too narrow to display them side by side, so remove that.

Result:

```css
.gallery-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

#galtitle {
  font-size: 500%;
}

.imggallery {
  height: 200px;
  /* width: 200px; */
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* display: inline; */
}

ul#list li  {
  /* display: inline; */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="gallery" class="no-padding content-section">
  <div class="gallery-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <h1 id="galtitle">Gallery</h1>
        <div class="imggallery">
          <ul id="list">
            <li>
              <img src="img/michael61.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <p>Visit flyer gallery</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="img/michael61.jpg" class="img-responsive">
              <p>Visit flyer gallery</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated css

```css
.gallery-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;

}

#galtitle {
  font-size: 500%;
}

.imggallery {
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

ul#list li  {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}
```